# ¿Cómo crear outliers de cambio transitorio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una serie de tiempo en la cual identifico un outlier de cambio transitorio, pero no se como poder agregarlo a mi estimación.

Son datos trimestrales y el TC se da en 2002.03, dejo la serie de como afecta

```
200203      1
200204      0.7
200301      0.49
200302      0.343
200303      0.24
200304      0.168
```

Comment: No llego a comprender tu pregunta. ¿a que te refieres con agregarlo a tu estimación?, ¿de que estimación estaríamos hablando? Y pregunta de ignorante: Si no eliminas la observación del TC, acaso no la estarías ya considerando en tu estimación?

Comment: Es para mejorar los residuos, al agregarlo lo tengo en cuenta como un valor atípico para que no me afecte los datos. Es una estimacion entre desempleo y pbi

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntarte esto: Si el outlier  no quieres que "ensucie" cualquier estimación, ¿no deberías eliminarlo del set de datos?

Comment: Disculpa, con agregarlo quiero expresar intervenir la estimación y que no la afecte, seria que NO tome en cuenta esos datos, podría decirse "eliminarlos"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema con los "outliers" es detectarlos, el segundo es quitarlos del set de datos para ajustar cualquier estimación o modelo. Por ejemplo, con un caso similar al que planteas:

```
df <- read.table(text="Periodo Valor
200203      1.4
200204      0.7
200301      0.49
200302      0.343
200303      0.24
200304      0.168", header = TRUE)

# Agregamos un número correlativo para cada período
df$n  <- 1:nrow(df)

df

  Periodo Valor n
1  200203 1.400 1
2  200204 0.700 2
3  200301 0.490 3
4  200302 0.343 4
5  200303 0.240 5
6  200304 0.168 6
```

Supongamos que ajustamos un modelo lineal a estos datos:

```
plot(df$Valor)
abline(lm(Valor ~ n, data=df), col="blue", lwd=3, lty=2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos detectar los outliers de la forma clásica, es decir: `Q1 - 1.5 * IQR` y 
`Q3 + 1.5 * IQR` que es la forma en que se los identifica en un `boxplot`, por lo que podremos usar `boxplot.stats()` que nos da varios de los valores de un `boxplot` pero sin graficarlo.

```
# Detectamos los outliers
outliers <- boxplot.stats(df$Valor)$out
```

En tu ejemplo consideras el valor del primer período como un outlier, sin embargo no lo es usando la formula clásica, por eso en este ejemplo, subí este valor a 1.4. De cualquier forma, que consideres un outlier, si buscas que no afecte el modelo o estimación, deberás eliminarlo del conjunto de los datos:

```
df_sin_outliers <- df[-(df$Valor == outliers), ]
```

Y ahora repetimos el modelo, sin los "outliers":

```
plot(df.sinoutliers$Valor)
abline(lm(Valor ~ n, data=df.sinoutliers), col="blue", lwd=3, lty=2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]